# Keep Track of users selecting in SQL sybase

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase

I am making a project where i am making a log system for a database, and i already did it for the Delete, Update and Insert actions using triggers, i am using Sybase Central.
But i also want to keep in the log tables when a user Selects anything, but i don't really know how to do that, i was thinking maybe using stored procedures?
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Why is there mysql tag for this question?

Comment: Aside auditing (which may be taxing on the backend), you can also trap utilization through middleware - application servers and web services (via request logging), for example.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about sybase = Sybase ASE then the only answer is to use database auditing.

Setting up auditing requires an additional system database *sybsecurity* and setting up the configuration to capture SELECT statements. Please set up the configuration according to the [manual](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01672.1572/html/sec_admin/X23329.htm).